# Handle decompositions of slice and ribbon disk exteriors

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $K$ be a slice knot in $S^3 = \partial B^4$. Then $K$ bounds a smoothly properly embedded disk $D$ in $B^4$. Let $\nu(D)$ denotes the tubular neighborhood of $D$.

Or we consider ribbon disks by excluding index two critical points.

Do we know $4$-dimensional handle decompositions of the slice disk exterior $B^4 - \mathrm{int}{ \nu(D)}$ for any slice $K$? At least for any ribbon disk exterior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can produce Kirby diagrams for the complement of a ribbon surface $S$.
Indeed, there is a procedure that is described in *Gompf-Stipsicz "4-manifolds and Kirby calculus"*.
I'll briefly explain that, for more details see pg 211-213 of that book.

First we perturb the projection $B^4 \simeq \mathbb{D}^3\times I \to I$ to a Morse function for the embedded ribbon surface $S$. One can prove that a critical point of index $k$ for $S$ corresponds to attaching an handle of index $k+1$ to the complement $B^4\setminus \nu S$ (see Prop. 6.2.1).

Consider a diagram for the ribbon knot together with the bands specifying the ribbon moves. When we do band surgery along these bands we end up with a bunch unknots. The disks they bound corresponds to the 0-handles of $S$, while the bands are the (2-dimensional) 1-handles of $S$.
Now, in order to build the complement $B^4\setminus \nu S$ we start with a 0-handle and then attach a (4-dimensional)  1-handle for each disk above followed by a 0-framed 2-handle for each band. The attaching circle of the 2-handle has to follow the band (really it is a perturbation of the band such that it links the unknots (now appearing as dotted circles)).

I do not know what you can do for a generic slice surface since in principle you would have the extra complication of attaching 3-handles.
In the book is mentioned that it is not known any example handle decomposition for  a topological slice disk  which is not ribbon.

Comment: Thus, the number of bands determine the number of $4$-dimensional $1$- and $2$-handles. For example, if we have stevedore knot or square knot, then the ribbon disk exterior has one $0$-handle and two $1$-handles and two $2$-handles, right?

Comment: You have to specify the bands first. 
The number of 4-dim 1-handles equals the number of disks/unknots that you get once you perform all the ribbon moves.
The number of 2 handles is the same as the number of bands.

Comment: For example If you perform a ribbon move to the Stevendore knot as shown in  example 1.7 of https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/sliceknots2.pdf
then you end up with  a 0 handle, 2 1-handles and a single 2-handle.

Comment: I see. The same picture can be drawn for the square knot by adding a vertical band from the left to the right trefoil. The result is the unlink.

Comment: As you said, we have a single $0$-handle, two $1$-handles and a single $2$-handle in both cases. Here, can we further do a handle cancellation?

Comment: The 2-handle will link algebraically once a dotted circles but generally  there will be more geometric intersections. So I don't know, is like trying to show that the manifold is not $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{D}^3$.

Comment: Thanks. Do we have any useful invariant detecting ribbon band number?

Comment: I read the relevant section in Gompf&Stipsicz. If the band number of a ribbon knot is $n$ then the ribbon disk exterior has always one $0$-handle, $n+1$ $1$-handle and $n$ $2$-handle, right?