# A knot in the solid torus and a Mazur manifold

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 4-manifolds, kirby-calculus

**Part 1:** The following picture is from Saveliev's book [Lectures on Topology of 3-manifolds](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110250367/html), page 130:

[image: knot]

He indicates that the knot drawn in the solid torus $S^1 \times D^2$ is homologous to $S^1 \times \{ 0\} \subset S^1 \times D^2$.

How can we prove such a claim? Do we know the classification of null-homologous knots in $S^1 \times D^2$?

**Part 2:** To obtain a Mazur manifold $W$, he says that we attach a $2$-handle to $S^1 \times D^3$ (the dotted circle) with framing $3$. Diagrammatically, we have:

[image]

If the knot is not null-homologous, where does the framing $3$ come from?

Comment: The knot shown is homologous to $S^1 \times \{0\}$ but it is not null-homologous.  You might want to fix your question and its title...

Comment: Why? If not, how can we talk about the framings of given knots? Because the next step is attaching a $2$-handle along this knot.

Comment: The knot shown has odd winding number in the solid torus.  (In fact, the winding number is $\pm 1$ depending on our choice of orientations.)  Thus the knot does not bound a surface.  Thus it is not null-homologous.

Comment: I am super confused! I have added a second part to the question...

Comment: You are using the terminology "null homologous" incorrectly.  I suggest correcting your question as this will continue to throw people off.  Also, why are you asking for a classification of these knots?  Seems beside the point of your question.

Comment: **Clarification:**  An oriented knot $K$ is called null-homologous in an oriented $3$-manifold $M$ if we have $[K]=0 \in H_1(M; \mathbb Z)$. In this case, it bounds a Seifert surface in $M$, and using it we can define a canonical $0$-framing and then all other framings.

Comment: @RyanBudney If the knot is not null-homologous, how can we declare a framing $3$ or any other integer?

Comment: You have the definition of null-homologous correct. But the knot you've drawn in $S^1 \times D^2$ does not satisfy that definition.  Try constructing a Seifert surface for it, and you will see why.

Comment: If you think of that solid torus as sitting in $\Bbb R^3$, then the knot is null-homologous, and does have a Seifert surface.  That's almost certainly equivalent to whatever convention Saviliev is using.

Comment: @RyanBudney I am now much more super confused! We know that $K$ is null-homologous in $M$ **if and only if** $K$ bounds a Seifert surface in $M$.

Comment: Correct, and your curve does not have a Seifert surface in $S^1 \times D^2$, that's why I asked you to try and construct one -- it does not exist.

Comment: Simple answer: the given knot is obviously homotopic to the knot with winding number $1$ and homotopy implies homology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two knots in the solid torus $U = S^1 \times D^2$ are homologous if and only if they have the same (signed) *winding number*.  Proving this boils down to computing the first homology group $H_1(U, \mathbb{Z})$.

For a given oriented knot $K$, its winding number can be computed by (a) finding an oriented meridian disk $D$ for $U$ which is transverse to $K$ and then (b) computing the algebraic intersection number of $K$ and $D$.

Finally you ask: "Do we know the classification of null-homologous knots in $S^1 \times D^2$?"  Well, there is a (very complicated) algorithm that decides if two null-homologous knots in $U$ are isotopic.  Using this we could produce the (infinite) list of all such knots (said list being complete and without repeats).

> where does the framing 3 come from?

I'll guess that he means either (a) the blackboard framing for $K$ or (b) the framing coming from the surface that $K$ and $S^1 \times \{0\}$ cobound. Luckily, these are the same in this particular case.

Comment: For the final part, do you suggest a reference?

Comment: The *blackboard framing* of a knot $K$ (drawn in the plane) is the normal vector field to $K$, thought of as an immersed curve in the plane. A quick google search found some research articles as well as pictures of framed blackboards, as well as pictures of knots equipped with the blackboard framing. For example: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-trefoil-diagram-with-its-blackboard-framing_fig7_343436301

Comment: The framing comes from the fact that you drew the knot in $S^3$! This is the "magic" idea of Akbulut's carving notation, that allows you to label framings of homologically essential knots $\#^g S^1 \times S^2$ by integers, once you fix a representation of $(\#^g S^1 \times S^2,K)$ in "dotted form" (which is exactly what you have). I have learnt this from Gompf and Stipsicz's book.

Comment: @MarcoGolla Thanks! I have two questions: What does _homologically essential_ knot mean here? Do you suggest section 5.4 of Gompf and Stipsicz's book?

Comment: "Homologically essential" means that its not null-homologous (sometimes with rational coefficients, but in this case it's the same, since there's no torsion). And, yes, I think it's Section 5.4.

Answer (score 4):

As @MarcoGolla mentioned, the framing can be controlled due to Akbulut's carving technology: a *dotted* circle notation. It was introduced in the following article:

> Akbulut, Selman. "On 2-dimensional homology classes of 4-manifolds." Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society. Vol. 82. No. 1. Cambridge University Press, 1977.

Let $U$ be the unknot in $S^3$ and $D_U$ be the ribbon disk in $B^4$ with $\partial D_U = U$. Observe that $S^1 \times B^3$ is the ribbon disk exterior of $D_U$, i.e., it is diffeomorphic to $B^4 \setminus \nu(D_U)$ where $\nu(D_U) \approx D_U \times B^2$.

Consider a ribbon knot with a ribbon disk $(K,D) \subset (S^3,B^4)$. Similarly, one can try to understand the $4$-manifold $B^4 \setminus \nu(D)$. The procedure of the construction of the Kirby diagram was answered, for instance [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380604/handle-decompositions-of-slice-and-ribbon-disk-exteriors/).

Once it is understood, one can also put a *dot* on the ribbon disk exterior. The reference is again Akbulut's book Section 1.1 and 1.4 about carving ribbon disks:

> Akbulut, Selman. 4-manifolds. Vol. 25. Oxford University Press, 2016.

It equivalently represents the ribbon disk exterior. See again Exercise 1.10 and Figure 1.22 in Akbulut's book.